# Wrong close reason on this question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, closed-questions, reopen-closed

[What does the keyword "transient" mean in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245600/what-does-the-keyword-transient-mean-in-java)

This question is in no way "too localized". It's a question about something in the specification of the most used programming language. It also is the second result when searching "java transient keyword" in Bing:

https://www.bing.com/search?q=java+transient+keyword&PC=U316&FORM=CHROMN

Maybe they meant the transient keyword itself is too localized :-)?

It should be closed as a **duplicate** pointing to [Why does Java have transient fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910374/why-does-java-have-transient-variables) , which has more complete answers.

Comment: Does it matter all that much?  It's a pre-Cretaceous question.  COBOL programmers still walked the earth when that question was raised.  SO had some good questions when that was raised.

Comment: @MartinJames That may be true but it would indeed be better to close as a duplicate pointing to the canonical Q/A.

Comment: Of all of the things you can spent your time on, chaning the close reason of questions has to be pretty low on the priority list.  There are already comments indicating the duplicate question.  This would consume a lot of people's time for no real gain.

Comment: @rene It matters because it's the first stack overflow result on a search engine and it should point to the right question. You spend the time of 9 users to reopen, and save the time of potentially thousands of suers who don't need ot look to the comments to find the correct answer.

Comment: Gotta love a question closed as "Too Localized" - but still has 80k+ views...

Answer (score 9):

I just reopened it and closed it as a duplicate.

That said, I did that because it's Friday afternoon and I was bored. In general, worrying about whether a 5-year-old question was closed for the right reason isn't worth the time.

Comment: Always a friday afternoon in iceland, isn't it?

Comment: @Zizouz212 So I've heard. And it's always 5:00 somewhere!

Comment: Notice that since the question is downvoted the question itself will be deleted

Comment: I don't see how the age of the question is relevant here since it's still showing up on search results. 81,719 people saw the question -- if half of them didn't read the comments, then 40,859 were directed to the wrong question. By giving it the correct close reason, you're helping future visitors find the right one. You're doing a good thing by fixing the close reason -- don't sell yourself short!